# python panel 'convert' invalid argument

Tags: python, panel

I was following the instructions of
https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Running_in_Webassembly.html
in order to convert a panel to HTML.

When I try to run `panel convert script.py --to pyodide-worker --out pyodide`

I get the error:

```
panel: error: argument{copy_examples,examples,build,info,init,json,sampledata,secret,serve,static,oauth-secret}: 
invalid choice: 'convert' (choose from 'copy_examples', 'examples', 'build', 'info', 'init', 'json', 'sampledata', 'secret', 'serve', 'static', 'oauth-secret')
```

Why is 'convert' an invalid choice and not listed? My panel version is
0.13.0

Answer (score 0):

This just work for Panel releases after version 0.14.0.